# Adding nodes to LinkedList cause Java's non-heap memory to leak with Serial GC

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

While experimenting with Java's memory usage with **Serial GC**, I noticed that as the number of nodes in a `java.util.LinkedList<String>` increased, not only did the heap kept growing but the non-heap memory usage also kept growing. However, with `ArrayList`, only the heap grew and non-heap memory stayed constant with the growing heap.

To test this, I ran a simple program that would keep adding `String` nodes to the LinkedList in an infinite loop and when it threw (controlled via `-XX:MaxHeapSize` flag) an `OutOfMemoryError` it would loop infinitely inside the catch block. Apart from the `-XX:MaxHeapSize` flag, I also used `-XX:MaxMetaSpaceSize`, `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize` and `-Xshare=on` flags which did not have any effect on this behavior. I kept their values constant with varying MaxHeapSize values. I also turned on the Native Memory Tracking. I repeated the same program with ArrayList instead of LinkedList. To measure heap memory usage, I noted the committed heap reported by the NMT. To get the non-heap memory, I subtracted the heap memory from the RSS reported by `smem`.
The experiment was repeated on **HotSpot 64-bit server VM 25.144-b01** and **OpenJDK 64-bit server VM 25.131-b11** and had similar results.

Below are the values (in MB) I recorded with OpenJDK server VM.

For LinkedList:

```
| MaxHeapSize | Heap | Non-heap |
| ----------- | ---- | -------- |
| 108.8       | 110  | 78.6     |
| 217.6       | 218  | 122.5    |
| 435.2       | 436  | 161.1    |
| 870.4       | 872  | 366.6    |
| 1305.6      | 1306 | 470.2    |
```

For ArrayList:

```
| MaxHeapSize | Heap | Non-heap |
| ----------- | ---- | -------- |
| 108.8       | 110  | 34.0     |
| 217.6       | 218  | 32.6     |
| 435.2       | 436  | 33.4     |
| 870.4       | 872  | 37.2     |
| 1305.6      | 1306 | 37.7     |
```

Looking at the implementation of `java.utils.LinkedList<E>` class does not indicate anything that might cause this behavior either.

What could be causing this difference in memory usage profile between LinkedList and ArrayList?

Comment: try running in interpreter mode

Comment: Can you post the program, you tested with? Did you try with another gc than serial?